# PowerShell problem using Select-Object with C# cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, select-object

I've written a simple C# cmdlet, let's call it `Get-Data`, that returns an array of objects.

```cs
protected override void ProcessRecord() {
    base.ProcessRecord();

    DummyClass[] refs = new DummyClass[2];
    refs[0] = new DummyClass("A", "big");
    refs[1] = new DummyClass("B", "small");

    base.WriteObject(refs);
    return;
}
```

This is the definition of `DummyClass`:

```cs
public class DummyClass {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DummyClass(string name, string  type) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;
    }
}
```

When I run the cmdlet by itself, I get the expected output - one row that has column headings and an additional row for each element of the array.

```
PS> Get-Data

Name Type
---- ----
A    big
B    small
```

However, when I pipe the output to `Select-Object`, I see column headings, but no data rows.

```
PS> Get-Data | Select-Object -Property Name,Type

Name Type
---- ----
```

I've even tried specifying the number of rows, with no luck:

```
PS> Get-Data | Select-Object -Property Name,Type -Last 2
```

Checking the type of `Get-Data` returns a data type of `DummyClass[]`, which is what I'd expect.

```bsh
(Get-Data).GetType().FullName
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on why there are no data rows when I use `Select-Object`? I don't know if it matters, but this cmdlet inherits from `System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet`.

Comment: do you see anything if you run `Get-Data | Select-Object -Property *`?

Comment: This is what I see: 

Count          : 2  <br/>
Length         : 2  
LongLength     : 2  
Rank           : 1  
SyncRoot       : {A, B}  
IsReadOnly     : False  
IsFixedSize    : True  
IsSynchronized : False

Comment: Sorry about the sloppiness of my previous comment, I'm still figuring out the formatting for comments - please ignore the <br/>, and each of the properties (Count, Length etc.) is on a new line in PS.

Comment: comments have very little formatting. anything even _slightly_ complex is best added to your Original Post. ///// since your property list is not showing `Name` or `Type` ... that  means you have some thing strange in your object. i recommend you save the object to a $Var and then see what `$Var.GetType()` shows you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that `DummyClass[]` doesn't have a `Name` or `Type` property, since it's an array. You can force it to unravel by nesting pipelines:

```
(Get-Data) |Select-Object Name,Type
```

---

Change this line:

```
base.WriteObject(refs);
```

to

```
base.WriteObject(refs, true);
```

to fix the default behavior.

The second argument (`enumerateCollection`) makes the command runtime unravel your array before sending it downstream to the next cmdlet in the pipeline.